# Enable View Library tab for Media module

Tags: 7, search, media

The screen shot for the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module  description shows the View Library tab. On my content type I can only see the first 3 tabs Uploads, Web and Library. The final tab "View Library" is not available. This site consists of 1000's of images thus such a tab is very useful. Let me know what is the way to enable this.

[image]

Comment: What version of Media are you using 1.x or 2.x?

This is a View page -- have you tweaked the `Pager` settings for this view at all?

Comment: Nopes it is not a view page, it is the screenshot from the module description page of the module. If a core module screenshot shows a functionality, one would wish it be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you've attached from the drupal.org media module page appears to be an outdated screenshot of the module. I believe you can use the "Library" tab. The "View Library" tab shouldn't be there in the latest version of the module.

There is more information on the tab title changes in this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1886994

Comment: So does that mean no way to search through those images, anymore?

Comment: The "Library" tab should be what you use to look through your media assets. Does that not show what you are looking for?